# yii2 - Change currency according to address

Tags: yii2, internationalization

I have an app where users from different countries are creating orders. I need to change the currency of the order according to the address of the user. I can get the country from the account details. My problem is, how should I change the currency based on the country?

Where can I do this in Yii2?

I understand that setting the currency can be done in main.php. But I need to be able to change the currency in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

- First, you must get user country from IP, for that you can use [yii2-geoip](https://github.com/lysenkobv/yii2-geoip).
- Then you must get country currency, for getting a list of country currencies to see [currency-list](https://github.com/srcagency/country-currencies/blob/master/data.json).
- Set session for store currency and change whole site currency.

Example:

```
<?php
$geoip = new \lysenkobv\GeoIP\GeoIP();
$ip = $geoip->ip(Yii::$app->request->getUserIP());
$currencies = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'), true);
foreach ($currencies as $currency) {
    if (strtoupper($currency['country']) == strtoupper($ip->isoCode)) {
        // set session and other jobs
    }
}
```

Example for `config/main.php`(for `yii2-app-advanced`) and `config/web.php` (for `yii2-app-basic`) :

```
<?php
return [
    //
    'on beforeAction' => function ($action) {
        if (!Yii::$app->session->has('global-currency')) {
            // your code for get found user $currency, maybe from db or ip
            Yii::$app->session->set('global-currency', $currency);
        }
    }
];
```

Comment: But how do I change the currnency of the site. This is my problem. I'm able to get the country of the user from his account. I however am not able to change the currency for the site. It wont change

Comment: Do you want to set currency in before all actions ? i didn't understand your problem

Comment: Yes. We can assume for now that I want to change the currency in any action. It's easy to take things from there

Comment: Ok, you can set it in main config in before action event

Comment: Can you give an example pls? :)